# Good way to see which condition is met in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have three different `if conditions` and want to see which conditions are met.

I thought I could work this with an empty list and append 1 if the condition is met and 0 otherwise.

```
check_list = []
sample = [1,4,7]
fixed_number = 5

if sample[0] < fixed_number:
    check_list.append(1)
else:
    check_list.append(0)
    
if sample[1] < fixed_number:
    check_list.append(1)
else:
    check_list.append(0)
    
if sample[2] < fixed_number:
    check_list.append(1)
else:
    check_list.append(0)


check_list
```

The desired output in this case:

```
[1,1,0]
```

How can I make this code short and pythonic?

Answer (score 2):

Simply this:

```
check_list = [s < fixed_number for s in sample]
```

if you really care having 0s and 1s, use `int(s < fixed_number)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
check_list = []
sample = [1, 4, 7]
fixed_number = 5

for i in sample:
    if i < fixed_number:
        check_list.append(1)
    else:
        check_list.append(0)

print(check_list)
```

You can use a loop to check the condition at once instead of calling every time.